# Exception handling inside shared library

Tags: android, c++, exception, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I cross-compile shared library PC to arm with NDK (llvm compiler) with -fexceptions flag and test it dynamically loading from executable on target android device.

In library code i have exceptions and handlers which does not go outside the library and all try-catch is inside.

In my test executable i load library it with dlopen( ... RTLD_NOW), and try-catch work fine. (I actually tried different flags but anyway exceptions handled fine)

Then i have another 3rd party executable which calls my library. I presume that my library is loaded the same way like i do but not sure. But this time exception don't work, it crashes

Test code inside library (not API extern "C" function)

```
logcat("1");
try {
  throw 1;
} catch (...) {
  logcat("2");
}
```

"2" always happen in my executable and never happens in 3rd party executable (crash happens)

I also checked malloc-debug flag on the device, it is not set (in build.prop)

My question is: Is there any way to 3rd party executable to change exception policies for my library (taking in consideration that try-catch all inside shared library), or any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Does the 3rd party executable and your library link against the same STL implementation? (if not, then you must somehow ensure that they do)

Comment: @Michael if i link stl static to library how can it matter?

Comment: It matters if the executable and library ever try to communicate with eachother. Quoting from the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html): _"An application should not use more than one C++ runtime. The various STLs are not compatible with one another. As an example, the layout of std::string in libc++ is not the same as it is in gnustl. Code written against one STL will not be able to use objects written against another. This is just one example; the incompatibilities are numerous"_.

Comment: @Michael so, if it's the case -- does it mean if i re-compile 3rd library code on my PC, or author of 3rd party library re-compile mine code the problem should go away? And is there a way to check it, maybe through tombstone analyse?

Comment: I don't know if this is what's causing your particular problems. It was more of a _"Make sure you're doing this correctly before proceeding with any other debugging"_ type of comment.

Comment: Can you post the crash stack? From your description, the C++ runtime difference should not matter, but which STL does your library use?

Comment: how does STL matter here if the author says exceptions don't go over the executable-library boundary? as long as the library maintains C interface, it's not a problem to use different runtime